# search service application creation fails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

Fail to create the SharePoint search application service: 
the error is :

> Errors occurred when configuring the application of search service. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The user is not allowed to perform this action.

[image]

then:

[image]

Comment: Try using an account which has higher privileges. ex using Farm Admin account

Comment: i got the same error even i changed to Farm Admin Account

Comment: what permissions does the farm account have on the config db and on SQL in general?

Comment: public i tried to add others roles like db_owner, i got the following message impossible to modify the db_owner role, because it does not exist or you do not have the authorization